# Very strange results with row names. Is this a bug?

Tags: r

I have a file with this content (tab separated):

```
bin_id  chr bin EURO.hz
chrF1_17700000  chrF1   17700000    102
chrF1_17800000  chrF1   17800000    199
chrF1_17900000  chrF1   17900000    398
chrF1_18000000  chrF1   18000000    410
chrF1_18100000  chrF1   18100000    342
chrF1_18200000  chrF1   18200000    447
```

I load it with:

```
jo <- read.table("tmp.tsv",header=T,row.names=1,sep="\t")
```

And everything goes fine.

Then, when I do:

```
jo["chrF1_1800",]
```

I get row name "chrF1_18000000":

```
                 chr      bin EURO.hz
chrF1_18000000 chrF1 18000000     410
```

Note the different number of zeros. To rephrase the problem: although row names "chrF1_180000" or "chrF1_180" do not exists, R returns "chrF1_18000000".

I have tried this in two different machines (linux, mac) with different R versions (3.0.1 (2013-05-16) and R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)).

This kind of behaviour is completely unexpected to me (and is responsible of many errors in my scripts). Is this a bug???

Thanks!
Federico

Comment: There seems to be the recommendation among some R experts never to use row names. I’m getting around to their point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting a `data.frame` by row names uses *partial matching*, as stated in the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) :

> Both [ and [[ extraction methods partially match row names. By default
>   neither partially match column names, but [[ will if exact = FALSE
>   (and with a warning if exact = NA). If you want to exact matching on
>   row names use match, as in the examples.

If you want exact matching, you can use [match](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html) function e.g. :

```
# partial matching does not work
jo[match("chrF1_18000",row.names(jo)),] 
#       chr bin EURO.hz
#   NA <NA>  NA      NA

# exact matching works
jo[match("chrF1_18000000",row.names(jo)),]
#                   chr      bin EURO.hz
#  chrF1_18000000 chrF1 18000000     410
```

Answer (score 0):

or use `subset`

```
 subset(jo, rownames(jo)=="chrF1_1800")
 #[1] chr     bin     EURO.hz
 #<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
 subset(jo, rownames(jo)=="chrF1_18000000")
   #             chr      bin EURO.hz
  #chrF1_18000000 chrF1 18000000     410
```

`grep`

```
 jo[grep("\\<chrF1_1800\\>",row.names(jo)),]
 #[1] chr     bin     EURO.hz
 #<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```